# Python Networkx Weight Labels Positioning

Tags: python, graph, networkx

The code below produces a very "dodgy" placement of the labels for edge weights in a graph. Please see image. I would like to have a better placement (close to the midpoint of each line), while still taking advantage of the automatic positioning of the nodes - i.e. I don't want to have to manually position the nodes.

[image]

Any ideas please? Also there is a warning -  `The iterable function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use np.iterable instead.` which would be good to address if anyone knows how.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C"])
G.add_edge("A", "B", weight=5)
G.add_edge("B", "C", weight=7)
G.add_edge("C", "A", weight=2)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=weights)

plt.show()
```

Comment: just replace `nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)` with `nx.draw_networkx(G,pos, with_labels=True)`

Comment: Awesome thanks. - If you make it an answer I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of draw_networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html):

> ```
> draw_networkx(G, pos=None, arrows=True, with_labels=True, **kwds)
> Parameters:   
> [...]
> pos (dictionary, optional) – A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values. If not specified a spring layout positioning will
> be computed. See networkx.layout for functions that compute node
> positions.
> ```

So, if you do not pass `pos` explicitly, a spring_layout is generated, but this won't be identical to the layout that you generate through

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

, because calling nx.spring_layout(G) twice gives different results:

```
for a in [0,1]:
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    print(pos)
```

output:

```
{'A': array([ 0.65679786, -0.91414348]), 'B': array([0.34320214, 0.5814527 ]), 'C': array([-1.        ,  0.33269078])}
{'A': array([-0.85295569, -0.70179415]), 'B': array([ 0.58849111, -0.29820585]), 'C': array([0.26446458, 1.        ])}
```

So, passing the same `pos` to both drawing functions solves the problem:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=weights)
```