# Networkx node positioning layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to create an undirected, weighted, and fully connected graph with networkx. My goal is to adjust edge length by the weights. Since I will have huge number of nodes, I don't want to specify their position one by one.

I was able to achieve this with nx.draw(G) but instead I need to use nx.draw_networkx_nodes() and nx.draw_networkx_edges() separately and when I do that the node positions don't look same as the result of nx.draw(G). What I mean by this is that nodes do not get positioned according to their edge weights.

Which node positioning algorithm fits best for that ?

Comment: Please could you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have a clearer idea of the problem?

Comment: [does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57746178/python-networkx-weight-labels-positioning/57746353#57746353)